# Logcat activity lifecycle without putting Log on code

Tags: android, android-activity, monitoring, logcat, lifecycle

Is there a way to monitor the lifecycle activity in abd logcat without putting the 
`Log("some activity");` on the code?

PS: I know the existence of https://github.com/stephanenicolas/loglifecycle

I want to be able to monitor my app lifecycle without describing all the logs or even to monitor the lifecycle of any app installed in a rooted device.

Comment: Be more specific about what you want to "monitor". Is this just for development so you can see when the lifecycle events are called? Or is there something you need in a live production app?

Comment: I need the logcat on a live app. My objective is to get all the logcat on a working device independently of the app to see performance in benchmarks of overclocking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

extend the Application class. There, override onCreate and you can then call

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks());
```

Where "MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks()" is a class that implements the ActivityLifecycleCallbacks interface. This interfaces lets you intercept activity lifecycle invocations for things like this. In fact, I do exactly what you're describing in my app by declaring the impl of the interface as a static inner class of my Application extension:

```
private static final class MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("","onActivityCreated:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
    }

    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
        Log.d("","onActivityDestroyed:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
    }

    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        Log.d("","onActivityPaused:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
    }

    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        Log.d("","onActivityResumed:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
    }

    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity,
                                            Bundle outState) {
        Log.d("","onActivitySaveInstanceState:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
    }

    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        Log.d("","onActivityStarted:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
    }

    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        Log.d("","onActivityStopped:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
    }
}
```